# Standard/best color schema for D3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there any standard/best color schema for D3.js? I used some colors but the UI is not good. Color combinations are not good. So if there is anything tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a set of standard ordinal scales described in the api docs:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors

You can use them like so:

```
var colors = d3.scale.category20();

d3.select("body").selectAll("text")
   .data(d3.range(0,20))
   .enter().append("p")
   .text(function(d){return "Data point "+d})
   .style("color", colors)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4xBL/

If you clone The d3 source, it [also includes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/lib/colorbrewer) the color brewer categorical color scales. You can learn more about them here:

http://colorbrewer2.org/